# docker: unauthorized: authentication required on manjaro OS

Tags: linux, docker, manjaro

I'm not so good with docker or Linux, anyway I can't run docker images. I just install clear Linux OS (tried twice), and tried to install docker and start some containers.

I can run `docker run hello-world` and I got correct data, but if I do `docker run ubuntu` it's loading about 5 min and then I got an error:

```
[york@york docker-git]$ docker run ubuntu
Unable to find image 'ubuntu:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu
docker: unauthorized: authentication required.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I tried different images like nginx or java, same. 
Of course i made `docker login` same...

Also tried make some stuff with MTU, putted mtu: 900, 1454, 1500 in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`, but maybe do something wrong here. Or any other places.

**My steps**

1. Install docker
2. `systemctl start docker`
3. `systemctl enable docker`
4. `docker run ubuntu`

OS: Manjaro KDE

#### wget

```
[york @ york ~] $ wget https://google.com/
--2020-05-06 22: 19: 45-- https://google.com/
Certificate loaded CA "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
Recognized by google.com (google.com) ... 64.233.161.113, 64.233.161.101, 64.233.161.139, ...
Connection to google.com (google.com) | 64.233.161.113 |: 443 ... connection established.
HTTP request sent. Waiting for an answer ... 301 Moved Permanently
Address: https://www.google.com/ [transition]
--2020-05-06 22: 19: 46-- https://www.google.com/
Recognized by www.google.com (www.google.com) ... 64.233.164.104, 64.233.164.105, 64.233.164.99, ...
Connection to www.google.com (www.google.com) | 64.233.164.104 |: 443 ... the connection is established.
HTTP request sent. Waiting for a response ... 200 OK
Length: no data [text / html]
Save to: "index.html.1"

index.html.1 [<=>] 18.54K --.- KB / s for 0.09s

2020-05-06 22:19:46 (216 KB / s) - “index.html.1” was saved [18984]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. sign up in : https://hub.docker.com/
2. login in the shell : docker login
3. docker run ubuntu

Comment: made it, doesn't help

Comment: can you check if the proxy line is commented or not in /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/https-proxy.conf ?

Comment: dont have folder `docker.service.d`

Comment: maybe problem in the clock synchoronozation  , can you wget to any https page ?

Comment: added above in question